# Difference between VBA.CBlah and CBlah

Tags: vba, addressof

Weird observation:

Normally when I want to save an address to a function in a variable, I do something like this:

```
Function getAddress(ByVal func As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    getAddress = func
End Function

Sub printAddress()
    Dim functionPointer As LongPtr
    functionPointer = getAddress(AddressOf myFunc)
    Debug.Print functionPointer
End Sub
```

However I just discovered I can use a 1-liner

```
functionPointer = VBA.CLngPtr(AddressOf myFunc)
```

while

```
functionPointer = CLngPtr(AddressOf myFunc)
```

... does not work and raises

> *Compile error:*
>
> *Expected: expression*

What's going on? The only difference as far as I'm aware is that `CLngPtr` is declared in the globals (class?) whereas `VBA.CLngPtr` is explicitly qualified, but I have no idea why that would lead to the observed behaviour (they both point to the same function don't they?)

Comment: *Compile Error: Expected Expression?*  Is that what you have without qualifying `VBA.CLngPtr`? If so, I can reproduce it, but I haven't a clue why...

Comment: @DavidZemens yep, should've put that in the question. Then if I try to run the code with `F5` I get *Compile Error: Syntax Error*

Comment: I think it has to do with the AddressOf operator because `VBA.CLngPtr(avar)` and `ClngPtr(avar)` work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be not very obvious if you used the default IDE settings which the keywords and identifiers aren't really set that differently. Here's how it looks when you use different colors:
[image: Sample Code]

You can see that `CLngPtr` lights up like a christmas tree and looks just like any other keywords. Compare this with `Abs`, which is also a function but stays light blue, as if it was just an identifier.

This is a hint that `CLngPtr` is optimized by VBA compiler so it's actually inlining the method<sup>1</sup>, which is why you get error if you try to use `CLngPtr` as an expression. However, a `VBA.CLngPtr` is a proper function and thus can be used as a part of an expression but with very slight performance penalty due to non-optimizing route.

You would see the same thing with say, `CLng` or any conversion functions, and even `Mid` the statement (not function). There are several functions within `VBA` that may get inlined by the compiler and usually can be differed by whether they turn into keywords or not. Note also that the parenthesis are colored differently.

Heck, even `Debug.Print` gets the special treatment, too and if you are familiar with it, you may know that it's not exactly a class nor a module, yet you can't `Print` without `Debug`.

---

1. When we refer to "inlinling" here, we are talking about what the VBA compiler is doing at lower level, below than what we see at the source code level. From the source code, `C***()` and `VBA.C***()` are basically the same thing. However, the VBA compiler can and will try to optimize those bits, by internally rearranging the machine instructions for converting (or whatever the inlined function is doing). The effect of rearranging the instruction is that it might no longer be compatible in all contexts. In this case, I can imagine (but do not know for a fact!) that `CLngPtr()`'s inlined instructions returns a value, rather than a reference, which is incompatible for a parameter declaration, which is why we get a syntax error when we try to use it as a parameter. Note this does not happen with `AddressOf` -- any other function on the LHS will have the same syntax error, so it has nothing to do with the `AddressOf` and everything with the method being inlined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this means: *it's actually inlining the method*? And maybe (if you can) explain why this doesn't recognize `AddressOf func` as an expression?

Comment: Added an explanation but keep in mind that I do not have full knowledge so I might be wrong in some spot but hopefully that helps explains.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more weirdness to ponder...

With the noted compile error in the comment, this works ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)):

```
Sub TestCasting()
    Dim value As Variant
    Debug.Print "value cast with     CBool  : " & CBool(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CBool  : " & VBA.CBool(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CByte  : " & CByte(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CByte  : " & VBA.CByte(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CCur   : " & CCur(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CCur   : " & VBA.CCur(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CDate  : " & CDate(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CDate  : " & VBA.CDate(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CDbl   : " & CDbl(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CDbl   : " & VBA.CDbl(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CDec   : " & CDec(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CDec   : " & VBA.CDec(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CInt   : " & CInt(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CInt   : " & VBA.CInt(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CLng   : " & CLng(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CLng   : " & VBA.CLng(value)

    '--- Compile Error: Sub or Function not found
    '    (error displayed at run time)
    'Debug.Print "value cast with     CLngLng: " & CLngLng(value)
    'Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CLngLng: " & VBA.CLngLng(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CLngPtr: " & CLngPtr(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CLngPtr: " & VBA.CLngPtr(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CSng   : " & CSng(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CSng   : " & VBA.CSng(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CStr   : " & CStr(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CStr   : " & VBA.CStr(value)

    Debug.Print "value cast with     CVar   : " & CVar(value)
    Debug.Print "value cast with VBA.CVar   : " & VBA.CVar(value)

End Sub
```

And adding to your code example above:

```
Function myFunc() As String
    myFunc = "help!"
End Function

Function getAddress(ByVal func As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    getAddress = func
End Function

Sub printAddress()
    Dim functionPointer As LongPtr
    functionPointer = getAddress(AddressOf myFunc)
    Debug.Print functionPointer
    functionPointer = VBA.CLngPtr(AddressOf myFunc)

    '--- Compile Error: Syntax Error
    '    (error displayed in red in VBA Editor)
    'debug.Print CLngPtr(AddressOf myFunc)
    'functionPointer = CLngPtr(AddressOf myFunc)
    Debug.Print functionPointer
End Sub
```