# Returning the address of a procedure to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, timer, addressof

first at all sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

I'd like to associate the address of a procedure that I created to a variable. Actually, I'm using a Windows Timer and in the Timer code, the function SetTimer is used this way :

```
    Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 0.1 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf move2)
End Sub
```

I'd like to replace "AddressOf move2" with a public variable and to do so I need to obtain the address of the procedure but I don't know how to do this. 
I tried to write

```
variable = AddressOf move2
```

And it doesn't work (variable type = long)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ac49ac7-b51c-4be7-83ea-864b7ee349dc/settimer-problem?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 0):

That is easy to implement. The only thing you didn't tell us is the "bitness" of your Excel. Well, I'm using Excel2019 64Bit. So, in my case, I'm using ***LongLong*** integers (8 Bytes). If you're running a 32Bit version, you have to account for that. On 32Bit platforms, you do not have **LongLongs**, but **only Long** integers (4 Bytes). I just mention that, because you wrote:

> And it doesn't work (variable type = ***long***)

The best thing you can do is declare your pointer variable of type ***LongPtr***. A ***LongPtr*** is not really a type of its own, but a neat feature that was introduced with VBA7. Any integer variable you declare as of type ***LongPtr*** is a ***Long*** on 32Bit systems and a ***LongLong*** on 64Bit systems.

In the declaration section of your module set your variable to

```
Public LngPtrMove2 As LongPtr
```

If you still running VBA6 you can use

```
Public LngPtrMove2 As Long ' for 32Bit
```

or, on a 64Bit system, you can use conditional compilation if you have to support backward-compatibility:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Public LngPtrMove2 As LongLong
#Else
    Public LngPtrMove2 As Long
#End If
```

Now, use the following function to assign the function pointer to your public variable on a 64Bit system running VBA 7 like so:

```
Public Function LngPtrMove2() As LongPtr
    LngPtrMove2 = VBA.CLngPtr(AddressOf move2)
End Function
```

On a 64Bit VBA 6 and on all 32Bit systems use this:

```
Public Function LngPtrMove2() As Long
    LngPtrMove2 = Vba.CLng(AddressOf move2)
End Function
```

Please be aware of two things:

1. You cannot test the assignment in the VBE Immediate Window!
2. You must keep the leading "VBA." in all calling variants. For more information read this SO question: [Difference between VBA.CBlah and CBlah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395851/difference-between-vba-cblah-and-cblah/57396732#57396732)

Hope this helps :-)